# Getting rid of current traces of MySQL so that I can re-install afresh

Tags: mysql

I installed MySQL server 8 on Ubuntu 20.04 which I needed to remove so that I could install [5.6.51](https://downloads.mysql.com/archives/get/p/23/file/mysql-server_5.6.51-1debian9_amd64.deb-bundle.tar). I did apt-get remove mysql-server etc and it got stuck in 64% which I halted and rebooted. I tried installing 5.6.51 which got stuck too. I did sudo rm lock-frontend in /var/lib/dpkg/. Now Im trying to remove 5.6.51 and do a fresh install but remove is saying its "Setting up mysql-community-server (5.6.51-1debian9)"

I even did `sudo apt autoremove` - it got stuck at 93% :

```
Removing libgupnp-1.2-0:amd64 (1.2.3-0ubuntu0.20.04.1) ...
Removing libgssdp-1.2-0:amd64 (1.2.3-0ubuntu0.20.04.1) ...
Setting up mysql-community-server (5.6.51-1debian9) ...
```

.

```
~$ sudo apt-get remove mysql
[sudo] password for ubuntu: 
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Package 'mysql' is not installed, so not removed
The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required:
  acl apg colord-data gnome-control-center-faces gnome-online-accounts gyp hplip-data javascript-common libc-ares2 libcgi-fast-perl libcgi-pm-perl libcolord-gtk1 libcolorhug2 libfcgi-perl
  libfprint-2-tod1 libgsasl7 libgsound0 libgssdp-1.2-0 libgupnp-1.2-0 libgupnp-av-1.0-2 libgupnp-dlna-2.0-3 libhtml-template-perl libieee1284-3 libimagequant0 libjs-inherits libjs-is-typedarray
  libjs-psl libjs-typedarray-to-buffer libkyotocabinet16v5 libllvm10 libmecab2 libnode-dev libnode64 libntlm0 librygel-core-2.6-2 librygel-db-2.6-2 librygel-renderer-2.6-2 librygel-server-2.6-2
  libsane-common libsnmp-base libssl-dev libuv1-dev libwebpmux3 mailutils-common mecab-ipadic mecab-ipadic-utf8 mecab-utils mobile-broadband-provider-info network-manager-gnome nodejs-doc
  printer-driver-postscript-hp python-pkg-resources python3-macaroonbakery python3-olefile python3-pil python3-protobuf python3-pymacaroons python3-renderpm python3-reportlab python3-reportlab-accel
  python3-rfc3339 python3-tz rygel
Use 'sudo apt autoremove' to remove them.
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 22 not upgraded.
4 not fully installed or removed.
After this operation, 0 B of additional disk space will be used.
Setting up mysql-community-server (5.6.51-1debian9) ...
```

Why is it Setting up mysql-community-server when I am trying to remove ?

[image]

```
sudo apt autoremove
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 22 not upgraded.
6 not fully installed or removed.
After this operation, 0 B of additional disk space will be used.
Setting up cups (2.3.1-9ubuntu1.1) ...
Updating PPD files for cups ...
Setting up man-db (2.9.1-1) ...
Updating database of manual pages ...
man-db.service is a disabled or a static unit, not starting it.
Setting up mysql-community-server (5.6.51-1debian9) ...

Progress: [ 38%] [#####################################################################................................................................................................................]
```

Answer (score 1):

I somehow go this worked out.

```
apt list --installed  | grep -i mysql
sudo apt remove <package name>
sudo apt-get remove --purge mysql*
sudo apt-get purge mysql*
sudo apt-get autoremove
sudo apt-get autoclean
sudo apt-get remove dbconfig-mysql
sudo apt --fix-broken install
```